# JavaScript: Updating DOM properties during a callback

Tags: javascript, dom, callback

When I update an .src in a Javascript .onclick callback, when is the image reloaded?

Does the browser fetch the image as soon as a new *src* is set, or does it only do it when the callback is finished?

Is this standardized somewhere?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46404528/9779026) suggests that the DOM only updates after execution, but I'm not sure if this is generally true. Also, do browsers optimize this anyway in the background?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about when the network request occurs?

Comment: Good question, yes! Although I'd also be interested in the timing of the rendering/repainting.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think you should be able to find out by opening your dev tools to view the network activity, and then create a long-running (blocking) operation after you set the `.src`, to see if the request gets blocked. My guess is that the request begins immediately.

Comment: As to rendering, I'm pretty sure that isn't going to happen until the callback is done, since getting position information of that or other elements would seem to cause a data race if the update happens sooner. But again, just a guess. The dev tools show timing data too.

Comment: maybe something around this part of the spec might help: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#when-to-obtain-images